# AWS: Connecting Lambda to a Secret doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-lambda

I am trying to connect a Lambda to a secret as per [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_resource-based-policies.html).

I set the following resource-based policy on the secret, and verified that it has indeed been set:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/my-lambda-execution-role"
        },
        "Action": ["secretsmanager:GetSecret", "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                "secretsmanager:VersionStage": "AWSCURRENT"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

However, I am getting timeouts when attempting to actually retrieve the policy (using Amazon's generated starter code for python3 client). I am executing the Lambda in the web IDE.

I tried it with and without the Condition filter. I also, just to be safe, granted the SecretsManagerReadWrite policy to the lambda execution role. No effect -- still timeouts.

I have a feeling that I am missing some important step there, but I have no idea what it could be...

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really get a *Timeout* and not *Access Denied* error?

If that's the case and you're getting timeout it's more likely that your **Lambda network configuration** is incorrect. If the policy was wrong you'd get *Access Denied*, not a *Timeout*.

For example if it's running in a VPC in a public subnet it may not have a Public IP assigned or if it's running in a private subnet there may not be a NAT gateway configured. Unless the Lambda needs access to VPC resources you may want to run it outside of the VPC (which is also the default, VPC-Lambda are a special case).

Hope that helps :)